# Catch cgi-like parameters within a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a `@WebServlet("/myServ")`. How can I retrieve the browser path if I enter `/myapp/myServ?param=123`? Can I get the "query" like string somehow?

Comment: Why exactly don't you use `request.getParameter("param")` the usual way? Do you want to get a mapping of all parameters? If so, just use `request.getParameterMap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, [HttpServletRequest#getQueryString](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) should do that.

Comment: and like @BalusC says, unless you really need the exact string, you can get nicely parsed parameter values easier using `#getParameter` and `#getParameterMap` (which also takes care of POST parameters).

Comment: Thanks, but I just need the whole query, so I'm fine with this!